# Facebook: fbml.refreshImgSrc How to refresh all images in an aplication

Tags: facebook, fbml

i'm modifing a old aplication that uses the (@Deprecated) FBML api, and we want to refresh all the images like http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fbml.refreshImgSrc/

is there any tips that you can tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution that i made was add some random parameter to the end of the url, so that way fb refresh the image:

http://miserver/img/img01.jpg?fbrefresh=random_parameter_123456

random_parameter_123456 = can be any random parameter like text (sdkhfsdhk) or numeric (23145434), the important is that never be 2 equals parameters... (timestamp its a good random parameter)

Regards,